# Counting to 100,000 and writing that to a file

Tags: python

I haven't used Python for a while but I decided to create a program today to help me with some work I am trying to do. I am trying to create a program that writes the numbers 1-100,000 with the symbol | after each but can't seem to strip the file after I create it so it shows like this: 1|2|3|4.

**My Code:**

```
a = 0
b = "|"
while a < 100000:
    a += 1 # Same as a = a + 1 
    new = (a,b)
    f = open("export.txt","a") #opens file with name of "export.txt"
    f.write(str(new))
f.close()


infile = "export.txt"
outfile = "newfile.txt"

delete_list = ["(","," "'"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

**export.txt:**

[image]

**newfile.txt:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a lot of work unnecessarily.

If all you want is a file that has the numbers 0-99999 with `|` after each, you could do:

```
delim = "|"
with open('export.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a in xrange(100):
        f.write("%d%s" % (a, delim))
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the second file is, but, in general, to open one file to read from and a second to write to, you could do:

```
with open('export.txt', 'r') as fi:
    with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fo:
        for line in fi:
            for word in line.split('|'):
                print(word)
                fo.write(word)
```

Note that there are no newlines in the original file, so `for line in fi` is actually reading the entire contents of "export.txt" -- this could cause issues.

Comment: Thanks but when I try the top one it says xrange is not defined and when I use the bottom one, the files are empty.

Comment: @Matt That means you're on python 3 -- just change `xrange` to `range` -- and the second block is just an example of how you could read from one file and write to another -- it isn't meant to do anything at all really.  In this case, it'd read the file created from my first block and print the integers on different lines (and write the integers without delimiter to the newfile)

Comment: So now the top one just counts to 99 but does it perfectly, thanks! Is there any way I can make it do all of them?

Comment: @Matt Sure just change `range(100)` to `range(100000)`.  Just be aware of the note at the bottom the answer -- the second block reads the whole file in at once.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! So much easier than what I was trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for writing your file:

```
numbers = []
for x in range(1,100001):
    numbers.append(str(x))

f = open('export.txt', 'w')
f.write('|'.join(numbers))
f.close()
```